Is a fermionic boson possible?
We know that bosons need an overall symmetric wavefunction. So is it possible for a boson to have an anti-symmetric spatial wavefunction and an anti-symmetric spin wavefunction? Such that upon particle position exchange the parity of the equation is still a +?
Is this possible?
Because to me this makes sense, but if I have 2 of the same bosons in the same state here then I get a wavefunction of 0, which goes against the fact that multiple bosons can occupy the same state. Hence this boson seems to display some sort of behaviour that is typical of a fermion, hence the title of my question.
Where am I going wrong or is my approach correct?
Edit: I am considering any type of bosons, so I am not limiting myself to spin 1 or 0 for example. I am merely considering the overall symmetric behaviour of the wavefunction needed for a boson.

"if I have 2 of the same bosons in the same state here then I get a wavefunction of 0" Can you clarify this statement?

@DanDan面 $\Psi(1,2)=(\phi(1)\psi(2)-\phi(2)\psi(1))(X_{AS})$ where $X_{AS}$ is some anti-symmetric spin function. Now if I have $\Psi(1,1)=(\phi(1)\psi(1)-\phi(1)\psi(1))$, then my spatial wavefunction is 0 hence the probability associated with this will be 0 no? So no boson found in the same state, despite both spin&spatial wavefunction being antisymmetric such that upon the exchange of 2 particles position we get a symmetric wavefunction, ie 2 odd functions multiplied together is an even function, satisfying the requirements for a boson.

If a wavefunction is symmetric under exchange of the particle labels, then it's a perfectly good bosonic state. If this just happens to arise as the product of antisymmetric spatial and spin states, that is not a problem at all: the overall wavefunction is still symmetric under exchange of the particle labels, and hence the wavefunction represents a perfectly good bosonic state.

Are you asking about bosonic bound states of fermions? Mesons?

A bilinear of fermions will commute with another bilinear of fermions, and thus be a boson; is this what you are asking about? Have you learned your quark model rules?

If a wavefunction is symmetric under exchange of the particle labels, then it's a perfectly good bosonic state. If this just happens to arise as the product of antisymmetric spatial and spin states, that is not a problem at all: the overall wavefunction is still symmetric under exchange of the particle labels, and hence the wavefunction represents a perfectly good bosonic state.
As an example,
$$
(\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2) - \psi(x_2)\phi(x_1))(\lvert 1:\chi\rangle\lvert 2:\gamma\rangle - \lvert 1:\gamma\rangle\lvert 2:\chi\rangle)
$$
is the product of antisymmetric spin and spatial states. (Here, $|\chi\rangle$ and $|\gamma\rangle$ are two distinct spin states, and the $\lvert 1:\chi\rangle$ notation means that particle 1 is in state $|\chi\rangle$.)


Because to me this makes sense, but if I have 2 of the same bosons in the same state here then I get a wavefunction of 0, which goes against the fact that multiple bosons can occupy the same state.

Yes, bosons can occupy the same state, but they don't have to.  The state above is perfectly good state in which the particles occupy distinct spatial states and distinct spin states. However, if you tried to form this combination where $\psi=\phi$ and $\chi=\gamma$, given by
$$
(\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2) - \psi(x_2)\psi(x_1))(\lvert 1:\chi\rangle\lvert 2:\chi\rangle - \lvert 1:\chi\rangle\lvert 2:\chi\rangle)=0\,,
$$
we get zero.  Thus, it's not possible to put the two particles in the same spin and spatial states while also stipulating that the spin and spatial pieces should be separately anti-symmetric. It's still possible to put the particles in the same state though, by forming the combination
$$
\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)\lvert 1:\chi\rangle\lvert 2:\chi\rangle\,,
$$
which is again symmetric under exchange of the particle labels.
Just for fun, we can note that the first state I wrote down is not the only symmetric one in which we put the particles in those states. The following one works perfectly fine, too:
$$
(\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2) + \psi(x_2)\phi(x_1))(\lvert 1:\chi\rangle\lvert 2:\gamma\rangle + \lvert 1:\gamma\rangle\lvert 2:\chi\rangle)
$$

Finally, I'll note that in a comment the OP made on their original post, it seems to me that they are misunderstanding some of the notation. (This is why I tried to spell things out by keeping particle labels 1 and 2 in the states explicitly, and labeling the actual single-particle states with different subscripts instead of 1's and 2's.) In the notation $\Psi(1,2) = (\phi(1)\psi(2) - \phi(2)\psi(1))X_{AS}$, the 1 and the 2 are the particle labels and the $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the single-particle state labels. So it makes no sense to then write $\Psi(1,1)$, because this would correspond to a single-particle state. This is the same as replacing $x_2$ with $x_1$ in the states I've written above: then the wave function only depends on a single particle's coordinate $x_1$; that's not a two-particle state!
